# Selenium WD + Python + HTMLTestRunner не генерирует отчеты

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pycharm

Всем привет!
Помогите, пожалуйста решить вопрос. HTMLTestRunner после прохождения теста не генерирует отчет. Даже пустой файл не создаёт. Если быть точным, но после запуска из консоли, файл создаётся, но пустым, и в саму консоль вываливается куча ошибок связанных как раз с HTMLTestRunner. Т.к. использую python 3.5.1, возникло предположение, что HTMLTestRunner не приспособлен к работе с это версией. 
Код для тестирования взял простейший:

```
import unittest
import HTMLTestRunner

class TestFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_test1(self):
        pass

    def test_test2(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(TestFunctions))
    # File
    buf = open("Report.html", 'wb')
    runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
        stream=buf,
        title='Test the Report',
        description='Result of tests'
    )
    runner.run(suite)
```

В самом теле HTMLTestRunner.py встречаются предупреждения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же, ранее там изменял одну строку по совету из одного известного [сообщества](http://automated-testing.info/t/webdriver-python-generacziya-otchetov/1782/22):

```
import StringIO
на

from io import StringIO
```

В общем, не помогло ни чего. Запускаем тесты из PyCharm - проходят, но отчёта нет. Запускаем из консоли - не проходит, отчет пустой, и то видимо сам файл создается благодаря `buf = open("Report.html", 'wb')`

Comment: Тема закрыта. Решение нашел. Могу сказать точно, что для Python 3.5.1 не подходит версия, HTMLTestRunner, которую я скачал с официального сайта. Для корректной работы пришлось вносить вручную изменение в его код учитывая специфику 3.5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тема закрыта. Решение нашел. Могу сказать точно, что для **Python 3.5.1** не подходит версия, **HTMLTestRunner**, которую я скачал с официального сайта. Для корректной работы пришлось вносить вручную изменение в его код учитывая специфику 3.5.1. Например:
 `from io import StringIO` - обязательно, так же надо учитывать, что в 3.5.х `str` уже декодированы и
 `ue = e.decode('latin-1')` 
не нужно, правильно:
 `ue = e`.
 Нужно учесть, что
 `has_key` 
 не используется, но подойдет "in"
 `cls in rmap`.

Comment: Типичная проблема питона -- несовместимости версий. Используйте   Ruby, и будет вам счастье.